# Conditionally replace values in column without specifying all cases

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I just want to replace some values in a specific column, is there a way to do this without specifying all the values present in the column?

The column is a separated column from another column which was split into three seperated columns (Division, department and section) hence it also contains null values.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you have provided the adjustments you need, in the final `Else` (that covers all cases not covered by your stated conditionals), you can choose to select a Column to fill the remaining values row-for-row:

[image]

Here I have selected the same column:

[image]

Which produces the following result:

[image]